# MassAssignmentException in updateorcreate in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am newbie to laravel I am using updateorcreate for model. But this is showing error MassAssignmentException end_time In Model Tasktimelog I am using protected $guarded = array(); Here is what I am Doing.

```
$endtask= Tasktimelog::updateOrCreate(
        [
            'task_id' => $taskid, 
            'action_type'=>4, 
            'user_id'=> auth()->id()
        ],
        [
          'end_time'             => $endtimeis,
          'total_time'           => request('totalseconds'), 
          'remark'               => request('remark'), 
          'actual_complete_time' => $diff, 
          'project_id'           => $getprojectid->project_id
        ]);
```

Comment: If you're using `protected $guarded = [];` (which you should share how you are doing that) make sure you don't also have `$fillable` set.

Comment: Share your model code

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn't let you to massive update fields of your database if you don't specificate it:

What you have to do is add the $fillable variable to your model with the fields that can be massively updated:

```
class Tasktimelog extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['task_id', 'action_type', 'user_id']; //and the rest of your fields
}
```

Laravel Doc: While $fillable serves as a "white list" of attributes that should be mass assignable, you may also choose to use $guarded. The $guarded property should contain an array of attributes that you do not want to be mass assignable.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions